# PERL regex related query

Tags: regex, perl

very recently i started to learn PERL so sorry if question appears very novice to anyone. I want to extract the lines started like this

```
gb|EU883669.1|  Nicotiana tabacum phenylalanine ammonia-lyase
```

but not like this

```
>gb|EU883669.1|  Nicotiana tabacum phenylalanine ammonia-lyase
```

I am using this code to do this `/(?<!\>)[a-z]\|/)`  but it matches both lines. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: That regex matches both lines g`b|` and >g`b|`

Comment: If this pertains to Perl, that tag should be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `^` anchor to make sure the line starts with alphanumeric: `/^[a-z]+\|/`

Answer (score 0):

`/(?<![a-z>])[a-z]+\|/` might work.